# TypeScript says type is 'any' when it's been explicitly set to something else

Tags: typescript

I have a dependency installed from which I'm importing a `TranslateModule` class. This is what I see when I hover its `forChild` method:

[image]

It says the return type is `any`. If I locate the class in my node_modules, this is what I see:

[image]

So the TypeScript declaration file says the return type is `ModuleWithProviders` - an interface that it has imported from `@angular/core`.

Can someone tell me why it doesn't pick up the correct return type and uses `any` instead?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the TranslateModule? It seems like `...importedModules` are the ones that cause troubles.

Comment: To add to this, an array will get type `any[]` if any of its elements are `any`.

Comment: @Temoncher If I remove `TranslateModule.forChild({})`, the error disappears.